# Define a default string type for an attribute of a model in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, types, model

i have this model

```cs
  public class AppInfo
  {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
    public string nick { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
  }
```

and i want to set default string types for `nick` attribute just like in typescript

```js
const plant: 'Tree' | 'Flower'
```

is there anyway to do this in c# ?

Answer (score 2):

In C#, there is not "short hand" way to do what you're describing, like in TypeScript. You would have to create a custom class for this purpose. It will have 1 readonly string property and throw exceptions in the constructor if the provided string isn't in your "allowed" list.

```cs
public class AppInfo
{
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
  public Plant nick { get; set; }
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
  public string version { get; set; }
  public string description { get; set; }
}

public class Plant {
   private readonly string[] AllowedNames = { "Tree", "Flower" };
   public string Name { get; }
   Plant(string plant) {
      if(false == AllowedNames.Contains(plant)) {
          throw new ArgumentException($"{plant} isn't allowed.");
      }
      this.Name = plant;
   }

}
```

In `AppInfo`, you will access the property with `nick.Name`.

Alternatively, you can add this logic to the `AppInfo` constructor directly. Although, if you intend to use this logic in other entities, creating a custom class is better.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string nick { get; set; } = "Default text";
```

if you don't set it manually, default text will be value of property

Comment: but i can say that this attribute can receive just two type of string, if receive a string that isnt in the types pattern, it throws an exception ?

Example :  public string nick { get; set; } = "Default text" | "Another Text";

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class AppInfo
  {
    private string _nick;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
    public string nick { get{ return _nick; } set { if(value != "Tree" && value != "Flower" ){ throw new Exception("Wrong text, fool"); } this._nick = value; } }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
  }
```

i updated little bit. validating value in property set.
this will throw error if you try to set obj.nick = "notFlower"